# Sequelize join tables and filter with source model

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have created relations properly for the following code to work:

```
const channels = await Channel.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Transaction
    }
  ],
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [{ agentA: address }, { agentB: address }]
  }
})
```

This includes all Transactions associated with the channel.

However, I want to filter this to include only the Transaction that has the highest `nonce` which is saved in the Channel instance itself.

For example this is how I think it should work, but this is definitely NOT working:

```
const channels = await Channel.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Transaction,
      where: {
        nonce: this.latestNonce // i want the latestNonce from the channel we are currently joining on
      }
    }
  ],
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [{ agentA: address }, { agentB: address }]
  }
})
```

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the latest transaction entry , you can do it like this ,

```
{
    model: Transaction ,
    required : false ,
    limit : 1 ,
    order : [['id' ,'desc']]
}
```

This is just raw query as I dont know all the fields of your tables , but this is how you can get expected result.

Comment: I assume if I wanted the highest nonce column instead of id, I would use `order: [['nonce', 'desc']]`?

Comment: Yes exactly , you can